Is it a felony to give a child a jump rope in Wisconsin?
Winconsin's statute 948.60 gives a rather detailed description of what constitutes a deadly weapon.  After outlawing nunchucks they go on to explain that this would include:

any similar weapon consisting of 2 sticks of wood, plastic or metal connected at one end by a length of rope

I'm pretty sure a jump rope is effectively two pieces of plastic attached by a length of rope.  So are we to arrest all those filthy felonious parents who encourage their kids to exercise?

the perhaps more interesting question is if someone committed an assault with a jump rope, whether the supplier could be charged


I'm pretty sure a jump rope is effectively two pieces of plastic attached by a length of rope.

Pretty much, yes.

So are we to arrest all those filthy felonious parents who encourage their kids to exercise?

No.  The quoted statutory text:

any similar weapon consisting of 2 sticks of wood, plastic or metal connected at one end by a length of rope

An item is covered by this provision if it meets all of the following criteria:

It is a weapon
It is similar to a nunchuck
It consists of 2 sticks of wood, plastic or metal connected at one end by a length of rope

Jump ropes do not satisfy the first criterion.

Or th second criterion.

@ohwilleke I thought about going into that.  It seems to me that similarity is so subjective that you couldn't be certain how a judge would rule on that.  Perhaps having two handles connected by a rope is sufficiently similar by itself.  On the other hand, while it's easy to conclude that a jump rope "could be used as a weapon" (a phrase that has some significance in the UK), it seems unlikely that anyone would conclude that it is a weapon.

Nunchucks are rather long sticks of wood connected by a short length of rope relative to the sticks and a fairly short overall length. A jump rope has a very long length of rope relative to the short handles.

@ohwilleke I know that.  Similarity is still subjective, especially since it could be argued that the statute explicitly identifies the critical elements of similarity as being "two sticks joined by a rope."m it's clear to me that the drafters of the statute did not mean to include jump ropes, but it is not clear to me that every judge would reach the same conclusion.

Judges draw the line and make subjective judgment calls all the time. It is part of the job. The law isn't deterministic. Different finders of fact can legally reach different conclusions from the same facts. But it would nonetheless be a strong argument to make, and you make all of your strongest arguments, not just one of them, since you can't know which one the court will find to be strongest.

Occasionally the media highlights a case where something not normally considered a weapon is declared as such by the courts for purposes of adjucating a weapon-related statute.  This probably wouldn't fly without an inciting incident to justify it.  This statute being applied in court would probably involve such an incident. I agree with ohwilleke: It's safer to apply both criterion, rather than only the first.

Makes sense to me.
I'm not a lawyer, but if you gave a jump rope to someone so that they can use it as a weapon, it makes sense that it'd be legally classified as a deadly weapon. If you wrap it around someone's neck and use the handles to pull, you could very easily kill someone with one.
Nunchuku aren't terribly effective weapons to start off with (you're usually better off using a stick the same length without the gap in the middle), so the legislation seems to set the bar pretty low for the efficacy required for a weapon to count as a "deadly weapon".
Using a jumprope (especially one with heavy wooden handles rather than light plastic ones) like a meteor hammer or flail would also be a plausible way to kill someone with one, if you hit them in a vulnerable location.
